# Getting connection string without using ConfigurationManager in C#

Tags: c#

In my mvc project i am getting case where i have to fetch connection string of the Web.config in my start project from class library. I need to avoid using ConfigurationManager from System.Configuration namespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static string GetConnectionString(string connName)
        {
            var xdoc = XDocument.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Web.config");
            var configs = xdoc.Element("configuration").Element("connectionStrings").Elements();

            var matchedConfig = (from c in configs
                                where c.Attribute("name").Value == connName
                                select c.Attribute("connectionString").Value).FirstOrDefault();
            return matchedConfig;
        }
```

--calling this method with "ResourceContainer" connection string

```
string connStr = GetConnectionString("ResourcesContainer");
```